# Is 5 an "untouchable number"?

Tags: number-theory

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5), 5 is an [Untouchable Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untouchable_number):

> Five is conjectured to be the only odd untouchable number and if this is the case then five will be the only odd prime number that is not the base of an aliquot tree.

...

> An untouchable number is a positive integer that cannot be expressed as the sum of all the proper divisors of any positive integer (including the untouchable number itself).

The proper divisors of 6 are 2 and 3, which sum to 5.

Is Wikipedia wrong?

Comment: From the examples in the article you link to, it is clear that the author considers $1$ a proper divisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A positive divisor of $ n$  which is different from $ n$ is called a proper divisor or an aliquot part of $n$.

So proper divisors of $6$ are $1,2,3$
which add to $6$...(Extra fact=$6$ is a perfect number and No perfect number is untouchable as it can be expressed as the sum of its own proper divisors. Similarly no amicable or sociable number is untouchable.)